# Vertical gap between Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, positioning

I'm trying to create a layout in Bootstrap that shows three blocks on a larger screen and two blocks on a smaller screen (the breakpoint occurs between *sm* and *md*).

[image: wanted layout]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">A - 50</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">B - 100</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">C - 75</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/zFnLs)

This however results in an unwanted vertical gap between block A and C.

[image: unwanted layout]

As I see it I have a few possible options to remove the vertical gap, but perhaps there is a better solution:

- Duplicate the html and use *visible-sm* and *visible-md* to show the wanted layout. On *sm* it would have a two column layout with the first column containing both A and C.

  - Disadvantage: The block content also needs to get duplicated, which might contain a lot of html
- Use JavaScript to move the block to the correct column (perhaps jQuery Masonry).

  - Disadvantage: I would rather have a CSS only solution
- Take a look at flexbox, css columns and css grid.

  - Disadvantage: Browser support isn't there

Comment: Flexbox is the easiest way to go, but as you say the browser support is not there yet ... saying that, if you are happy for older browsers to get the content in one column then go for that.

Comment: guys exactly same thing I was doing this morning; but using Flex method.

Comment: Perhaps using flexbox for newer browsers and having a slightly less optimal layout for older browsers will do, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

Imperfect untested solution at http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fvpLl. Key points:

- At small widths

  - break B out of flow
  - make container smaller

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<!-- note: sm -> container 50% -->
  <div class="row col-xs-6 col-md-12"> 
    <!-- note: sm -> div = 100% of container which is 50% -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 h50">A - 50</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 h100">B - 100</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 h75">C - 75</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Fragment

```
/* xs and sm */
@media ( max-width: 991px) { 
  .h100 {
    position: absolute !important; /* better to do with specificity, but quick ugly hack */
    margin-left:93%;
  }
}
```

Spacing is not perfect, but gives you a starting point for your experiments.

Note: this can be implemented using [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) and [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) (when it is ready) far easier - and the [latest alpha version of Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) does support flexbox.

Comment: Thanks! I sounds like a promising start

Comment: @Ruskin are you sure that the cotainer is supposed to be inside the row ? or is this just experimental ?

Comment: Can't remember, this was over a year ago

Answer (score 0):

I realize you said you'd prefer a css only solution, but in my opinion what you are trying to accomplish is not what the bootstrap devs had in mind when they designed their grid system.  I would use javascript to stick that sucker where you need it:

[jQuery/html/css solution](http://codepen.io/Jacob-McKay/pen/KCjpo)

I changed your columns to be containers (I called em buckets)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="leftBucket" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div id="A" class="h50">A - 50</div>
    </div>
    <div id="middleBucket" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div id="B" class="h100">B - 100</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBucket" class="hidden-sm col-md-4">
      <div id="C" class="h75">C - 75</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

---

Then I "borrowed" an approach to watching for media queries from the link in the comment below

**JS**

```
// stolen from: http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ($("#hiddenDiv").css("float") == "none" ){
    // small screen!
    $('#C').appendTo('#leftBucket');
    } else {
    //not a small screen :P
    $('#C').appendTo('#rightBucket');
  }
});
```

---

And added some rules for the hidden div (that I use to watch screen width)
**CSS**

```
#hiddenDiv {float:left;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
    #hiddenDiv {float:none;}
}
```

ps.  it's good to see people using hand drawn doodles to get their ideas across, that's how I like to break it down for people also :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Bootstraps grid indeed isn't intended for this. What I've currently implemented is a bit like your solution. JavaScript is used to create two bootstrap layouts, one for the two and one for the three column layout. Two `<div>`'s with `.visible-sm` and `.visible-md` are used combined with a onresize listener to move the widgets to the correct layout. P.S. hand drawn doodles are indeed wonderful!

Comment: Glad you came up with a solution, this solution reminds me of how Android handles UI's.  In xml you'd define two different layouts (one for landscape and one for portrait, for example) and inflate/populate the layout depending on the device orientation/screen size.  I think that's more elegant than what we've got to do with web dev where the solution to the problem is spread out across hmtl/css/js.  Who knows what web UI design will be like in a few years though, perhaps we'll have a more modular/cleaner design process :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a clever way of doing this. Rearrange the order. Put C before B and then use push and pull to swap the order

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">A - 50</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 ">C - 75</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col- col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">B- 100</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering BS is designed to support column reordering.  Have you run  this in a codepen and seen if the vertical gap is still there?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle with a wrapping div added with a fixed width.
For 320 screen size, reduced the wrapper width and also changed float of the B div to `float: right`
Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/2q785vp5/2/

[image]